# Docker/Compose: Define and use env variable

Tags: apache, docker, debian

on my github i'm creating a little fork from a debian minimal docker image. Its actually 5 packages which build up on previous:

```
debian-base-minimal
debian-base-standard
debian-base-security
debian-base-apache
debian-base-apache-php
```

On debian-base-apache i want to get a working env variable, which i can define later in docker-compose file. What should the env do?

Its should, if defined over docker-compose, write `ServerName $SERVER_NAME` at the end of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to set a globally Server Name. If empty, no new line should be written.

But why its should write nothing when its empty? Cauz on build the Dockerfile to an image shouldnt include the `SERVER_NAME`.

I already tried something like:
`echo "ServerName $SERVER_NAME" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

on my 040-debian-base-apache file. But on build its wrote `ServerName` in, cauz i didnt defined a value and its using `null`. If i set a default in Dockerfile (`ENV SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1`) its build the image with `127.0.0.1` and i cant change `127.0.0.1` via variable, cauz the variable already filled in with the value.

On ouput of the building with defined `ENV SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1` in Dockerfile (actually not in repo):

```
[...]
+ echo 'ServerName 127.0.0.1'
+ /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
Stopping Apache httpd web server: apache2.
ok.
+ /etc/init.d/apache2 start
Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2.
ok.
[...]
```

Its would be okay, if there stands default 127.0.0.1 cauz the apache can start. But i cant define it now in docker-compose.yml cauz its hardcoded 127.0.0.1 and not the output of a variable.

On ouput of the building with none defined ENV in Dockerfile (actually repo version):

```
[...]
+ echo 'ServerName '
+ /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
Stopping Apache httpd web server: apache2.
+ /etc/init.d/apache2 start
Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2 failed!
The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 228 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
ServerName takes one argument, The hostname and port of the server 
[...]
```

Can anybody help me to get this working? Would be nice to understand how it works.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the link to your github fork so that we can see what you have in the Dockerfile and docker compose files. Please add it to the question and also share the command you use to run them.

Comment: https://github.com/yfstein/docker-debian-base

Comment: As I said in my comment please add the link to your question and also the command you use to run them.

Comment: @Exadra37 i edited my top post with more informations, links, outputs and with which file i build all the things. Do you need anything else? I'm sorry but i dont know what u clearly mean with `add the link to your question`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've observed, every RUN command in the Dockerfile happens at `docker build` time, and in particular the contents of the file will be fixed based on what the environment variable was when you ran the build.  You want it to change based on the runtime value of the variable, which means you need to write a script that runs at startup to do this.

A typical approach is to write an ENTRYPOINT script that does the first-time setup.  The ENTRYPOINT gets passed the CMD (or whatever command got passed into `docker run`) as command-line arguments, so if it ends with `exec "$@"`, the last thing it does is launch the "normal" command.  You can use any ordinary shell script logic here, so I might write

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$SERVER_NAME" ]; then
  echo "ServerName $SERVER_NAME" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
fi
exec "$@"
```

Then you can provide this in your Dockerfile

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apachectl", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

(The `chmod` isn't necessary if you can guarantee the file has execute permissions on your non-Windows host.  The `ENTRYPOINT` must use the JSON-ish form.  If you have another image that builds on top of this, remember that the combined image gets only one ENTRYPOINT and one CMD; the very deep stack of images you suggest is a pretty unusual setup.)

Comment: Very thanks for ur help. Now i understand how it should work :) `the very deep stack of images you suggest is a pretty unusual setup` can u explain a bit more what u mean? Did u mean the depencys of images to run the apache-php or did u mean just things like php extensions etc.?

Comment: Most projects I've seen (even those in commercial production environments) have only one or two levels of images.  Five levels of images before you actually add any application-specific code seems overly complex.  In your repo, as an example, nothing in the (complex) "minimal" layer is usual or required for a Docker image.

Comment: As example it would be better do merge like minimal, standard, security to one image and clean up a bit so i've later just have the new debian-base-minimal which is the depency for apps like apache, apache proxy etc. and not minimal base for, standard, standard base for security, security base for app (in this example apache)?